# How to make a mail system that only makes mail messages for those who have at least 12 points?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

I have a code that creates messages for clients who have at least 12 points and with the if statement It  checks if it is more or less 12 points. So if it is less than 12 points then the system would  not create the mail message. I have tried to do this with my code however my if statements don't even work.
In the following code it opens "Db7" a document which is the mail message document with discounts.And the other one opens "data"contains client names so the names would be extracted into the mail messages.It decides by checking the spreadsheets  tab for points if they have  less than 12 then it  creates the message in a new document called message.

```
function g() {
    var db, doc;
    var files = DriveApp.getFilesByName("Db8i");
    if (files.hasNext())
        db = files.next();
    else
        return;
    files = DriveApp.getFilesByName("data");
    if (files.hasNext())
        doc = files.next();
    else
        return;
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(db.getId());
    var template = DocumentApp.openById(doc.getId());
    var message = DocumentApp.create("message") .getBody();
    var par = template.getBody().getParagraphs();
    var val = ss.getSheets()[0].getDataRange().getValues();
    var i, j, str;
    for (i=1; i<val.length; i++) {
        str = val[i][0] + "";

        if (val[i][0]=="1")
          str += "client";
          else
            str += "guest";


        var p;
        for (j=0; j<par.length; j++) {
            p = par[j].copy();
            message.appendParagraph(p); }
        message.replaceText("{name}", str);
        message.appendPageBreak();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the Execution transcript.

Comment: Also, please, clarify: 1) why do you concatenate `val[i][0]` with an empty string? 2) where are the `if` statements that perform the 12-point check that don't work?